# How to print a specific key value from an array of string in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to extract AMI ID from the below expression,

```
response = imagebuilder_client.list_image_pipeline_images(imagePipelineArn='arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:image-pipeline/demo',)
versions = response['imageSummaryList']
print(versions)
```

I am able to print all the array elements. But I need to return/print AMI ID only from this list/array.

Comment: What type of object does *response* refer to? If it's a dictionary just print the entire content then you'll see where the data are that you need

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`list_image_pipeline_images()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/imagebuilder.html#imagebuilder.Client.list_image_pipeline_images) documentation, the response is:

```json
{
    'requestId': 'string',
    'imageSummaryList': [
        {
            'arn': 'string',
            'name': 'string',
            'type': 'AMI'|'DOCKER',
            'version': 'string',
            'platform': 'Windows'|'Linux',
            'osVersion': 'string',
            'state': {
                'status': 'PENDING'|'CREATING'|'BUILDING'|'TESTING'|'DISTRIBUTING'|'INTEGRATING'|'AVAILABLE'|'CANCELLED'|'FAILED'|'DEPRECATED'|'DELETED',
                'reason': 'string'
            },
            'owner': 'string',
            'dateCreated': 'string',
            'outputResources': {
                'amis': [
                    {
                        'region': 'string',
                        'image': 'string',
                        'name': 'string',
                        'description': 'string',
                        'state': {
                            'status': 'PENDING'|'CREATING'|'BUILDING'|'TESTING'|'DISTRIBUTING'|'INTEGRATING'|'AVAILABLE'|'CANCELLED'|'FAILED'|'DEPRECATED'|'DELETED',
                            'reason': 'string'
                        },
                        'accountId': 'string'
                    },
                ],
                'containers': [
                    {
                        'region': 'string',
                        'imageUris': [
                            'string',
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
            'tags': {
                'string': 'string'
            },
            'buildType': 'USER_INITIATED'|'SCHEDULED'|'IMPORT'
        },
    ],
    'nextToken': 'string'
}
```

Therefore, you would use:

```py
for image in response['imageSummaryList']:
    print(image['image'])
```

Comment: Its printing arn of the Image. I need to print Image ID/AMI ID

Comment: Which field is that in? I suspect that it would be at the end of the ARN. You can use Python to extract that substring.

Comment: How to extract substring in python. I need to extract 'image': 'string'.

Comment: If it is that field, you can simply use `print(image['image'])` in the above `for` loop. I'll update my answer.